# Django sets a default value to model input

Tags: python, django

When I load the page, the value of the input is automaticly this:
[image: Issue Screenshot]

How is that possible?

views file

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FieldForm(request.POST, instance=Field(user=request.user))
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.creator_adress = get_client_ip(request)
            obj.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard')
    else:
        form = FieldForm(instance=Field)
    
    ......
```

forms file

```
class FieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Field

        fields = (
            'title',
            'url'
        )
```

models file

```
class Field(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creator_adress = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Here one input 
value= <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000001E180304250>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you are passing a reference to your `Field` model as the argument `instance`. Doing this places the representation of the model fields into your form fields when it is rendered. If what you are wanting is just a blank form when you load the page then just remove the `instance` argument and create your form in your `else` statment, like `form = FieldForm()`. The instance argument is only needed for a form if you are trying to pre-populate data into the form, for example if you made a view where you wanted to update information on an already created object you would pass an instance of your model to the `instance` argument.

Comment: Why should I remove this? Then I can't create multiple objects

Comment: What do you mean then you can't create multiple objects? This change would only stop those values from showing up in your fields when you are creating a new object.

Comment: Oh! You're talking about the form in the else statement, my fault. Works now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that I should have clarified which one.